# Cannot convert the pdf file into the CSV file

Tags: python, csv, pdf, spyder

I am a new python learner, I am struggling how to change the pdf file into CSV file by using Spyder.

Input

```
import tabula
dfs = tabula.read_pdf(r'C:\Users\home\Desktop\RN(G)_GazetteList.pdf.pdf', pages='all')

tabula.convert_into(r'\C:\Users\home\Desktop\RN(G)_GazetteList.pdf.pdf', "output.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')

tabula.convert_into_by_batch("input_directory", output_format='csv', pages='all')
```

Output

```
The output file is empty.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\home\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    tabula.convert_into(r'\C:\Users\home\Desktop\RN(G)_GazetteList.pdf.pdf', "output.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')

  File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tabula\wrapper.py", line 273, in convert_into
    raise FileNotFoundError(errno.ENOENT, os.strerror(errno.ENOENT), path)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\C:\\Users\\home\\Desktop\\RN(G)_GazetteList.pdf.pdf'
```

Thank you so much

Comment: You have a backslash before the drive letter "C:"

Comment: Hello snwfly, thank you for your answer. I deleted the backslash, however it still not work.

Comment: Output `runfile('C:/Users/home/Downloads/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/home/Downloads')
The output file is empty.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\home\Downloads\untitled1.py", line 6, in <module>
    tabula.convert_into_by_batch("input_directory", output_format='csv', pages='all')
File "C:\Users\home\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tabula\wrapper.py", line 305, in convert_into_by_batch
raise AttributeError("'input_dir' shoud be directory path")
AttributeError: 'input_dir' shoud be directory path`

Comment: Please research and/or ask a new SO question for this new error. The original error message is gone, therefore the purpose of _this_ question is fulfilled. You shouldn't paste this much code/error text into a comment, it's not well readable. Questions on StackOverflow should only deal with a single problem, so a new question is in order, if you don't manage to resolve the issue yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As a possible answer to serve as a reference. You could use `pdftables_api`:

```
import pdftables_api 
conversion = pdftables_api.Client('key')
conversion.csv('pdf_path','output_path')
```